# How to excel pivot a table, on which headers are aside?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

**In Excel I do have the following entries:**

[image]

**Now I would like to create a Pivot (or antother way) in excel to display a result like this. Of course in a simple, dynamic and automatic way:**

```
Group1:
-> John Doe, Luke Smith

Group2:
-> John Doe

Group 3:
-> Mike Cando

Group 4:
-> Luke Smith
```

**Unfortunately my pivot shows me the name as fields, not the groups:**

[image]

**Any way to change the name field with group in pivot? Or is there a better / simpler way, to achieve the result that I want?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Office 365 Excel:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$D$1,B2:D2="x"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

more dynamic including headers aside as requested (also Office 365 as a requirement):

`=LET(header,$A$1:$D$1, data,A2:D5, groupdata,INDEX(data,,1), xml1,IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(data<>"",header,""))&",","0, ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),""), xml,FILTER(xml1,LEN(xml1)<>0), leftxml,LEFT(xml,LEN(xml)-1), CHOOSE({1,2}, groupdata, leftxml))`
[image]

Withouth LET:
`=CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A5,LEFT(FILTER(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF($A$2:$D$5<>"",$A$1:$D$1,""))&",","0, ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),""),LEN(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF($A$2:$D$5<>"",$A$1:$D$1,""))&",","0, ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),""))<>0),LEN(FILTER(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF($A$2:$D$5<>"",$A$1:$D$1,""))&",","0, ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),""),LEN(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF($A$2:$D$5<>"",$A$1:$D$1,""))&",","0, ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),""))<>0))-1))`

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed writing it